# How to expand taxa annotations into separate columns in a data frame

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a taxonomic identifier data frame and I am trying to "expand" the taxa ID into separate columns.  I found and followed a previous question but am again stuck interpreting the final line of code.

Here are the first few lines of my taxa data frame:

```
> dput(toytax)
structure(list(taxa = structure(1:3, .Label = c("D_0__Archaea;D_1__Altiarchaeota;D_2__Altiarchaeia;D_3__uncultured archaeon;D_4__uncultured archaeon;D_5__uncultured archaeon;D_6__uncultured archaeon", 
"D_0__Archaea;D_1__Altiarchaeota;D_2__Altiarchaeia;D_3__uncultured euryarchaeote;D_4__uncultured euryarchaeote;D_5__uncultured euryarchaeote;D_6__uncultured euryarchaeote", 
"D_0__Archaea;D_1__Asgardaeota;D_2__Odinarchaeia;D_3__uncultured euryarchaeote;D_4__uncultured euryarchaeote;D_5__uncultured euryarchaeote;D_6__uncultured euryarchaeote"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("otu1", 
"otu2", "otu3"))
```

And I am trying to separate them out to look like this:

```
otu     Domain     Phylum         Class         Order               family              ...
otu1    Archaea    Altiarchaeota  Altiarchaeia  uncultured archaeon uncultured archaeon ...
.
.
.
```

all the way through to species (domain, phylum, class, order, family, genus, species).  My first step was to "clean" the annotations as seen below, yet this unfortunately did not work:

```
toytax$taxa <- gsub("D_0__[A-Za-z]+\\.D_1__[A-Za-z]+\\D_2__", "", toytax$taxa)
```

My second step was to extract these names into separate columns, also with no avail.

```
tidyr::extract(tax, taxa,
               c('domain','phylum','class','order','family','genus','species'),
               '(\\d+-\\d+-\\d+ \\d+:\\d+:\\d+:\\d+)\\s*([A-Z]+)\\s*(<.*?>)\\s*({.*?})\\s*(\\[.*?\\])\\s*(.*)')
```

It's clear I am not understanding how to refer to the characters in this way.  Any help is appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clean up (here with `stringr::str_remove_all()`) you just need to specify "D_\d__" where `\\d` means a digit. Then you can use `tidyr::separate()` on ";"

```r
library(tidyverse)

toytax %>%
  mutate(taxa = str_remove_all(taxa, "D_\\d__")) %>%
  separate(taxa,
           into = c("Domain", "Phylum", "Class", "Order", "family", "level5", "level6"),
           sep = ";")
#>    Domain        Phylum        Class                    Order
#> 1 Archaea Altiarchaeota Altiarchaeia      uncultured archaeon
#> 2 Archaea Altiarchaeota Altiarchaeia uncultured euryarchaeote
#> 3 Archaea   Asgardaeota Odinarchaeia uncultured euryarchaeote
#>                     family                   level5                   level6
#> 1      uncultured archaeon      uncultured archaeon      uncultured archaeon
#> 2 uncultured euryarchaeote uncultured euryarchaeote uncultured euryarchaeote
#> 3 uncultured euryarchaeote uncultured euryarchaeote uncultured euryarchaeote
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>